# android - videoView does AsyncTask only once / onPostExecute never gets called

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-videoview

I have 3 videos. depending on the `videoLong` I play the selected video with `videoView`.

**I have 2 questions:**

1. The first time a video is played it works. The video stops at the correct time and `finish()` is used. BUT any time after that `doInBackground` doesnt check the other if statements.
2. My onPostExecute never gets called.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   if (videoLong == 0) {
       videoView
               .setVideoURI(Uri
                       .parse("http://pv...70ab1aae7633.mp4"));
       videoView.seekTo(60000 * 10);// 10 mins
       videoView.start();
       new myAsync().execute();
   } else if (videoLong == 1) {

       videoView
               .setVideoURI(Uri
                       .parse("http://pv....mp4"));
       videoView.seekTo(60000 * 10);// 10 mins
       videoView.start();
       new myAsync().execute();
   } else if (videoLong == 2) {
       videoView
               .setVideoURI(Uri
                       .parse("http://pv....mp4"));
       videoView.seekTo(60000 * 10);// 10 mins

       new myAsync().execute();
       videoView.start();
   }
   }

   private class myAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

   int duration = 0;
   int current = 0;

   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       System.out.println("on pre execute");
       // alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PlayVideoActivity.this);
   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

       videoView
               .setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                       duration = videoView.getDuration();

                   }
               });

       videoView
               .setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                       // Do whatever u need to do here
                       System.out.println("video complete");
                       finish();
                   }
               });

       do {
           current = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
           // System.out.println("duration - " + duration + " current- " +
           // current);

           try {

               publishProgress((int) (current * 100 / duration));

               // System.out.println("time: " + current);
               if (current >= 610100 && videoLong == 0) {
                   System.out.println("video 1 done");
                   videoView.stopPlayback();

                   videoView = null;
               }
               if (current >= 610200 && videoLong == 1) {
                   System.out.println("video 2 done");
                   videoView.stopPlayback();
                   finish();
               }
               if (current >= 610200 && videoLong == 2) {
                   System.out.println("video 3 done");
                   videoView.stopPlayback();
                   finish();
               }
               if (mProgressBar.getProgress() >= 100) {
                   // System.out.println("error100");
               }

           } catch (Exception e) {
               // e.printStackTrace();
           }
       } while (mProgressBar.getProgress() <= 100);

       return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
       super.onProgressUpdate(values);
       // System.out.println("values: " + values[0]);
       mProgressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       System.out.println("on POST execute");


   }

   }

   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
   if (videoView != null)
       videoView.stopPlayback();
   videoView = null;
   System.out.println("back button pressed. stop playback");
   super.onBackPressed();
   }
   ```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: System.out.println? Change it to Log.d("tag", "on post execute");

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger to trace your code and see where it goes wrong?

Comment: @egor I did. no errors, but i did notice that doInBackground continues to work and onPostExecute never gets called. might be because of the if statements but I could not find an alternate way.